# Submodule of cyclic module

Tags: modules, cyclic-groups

I am reading On $M$-Projective and $M$-Injective Modules by Azumayya (https://msp.org/pjm/1975/59-1/pjm-v59-n1-p02-s.pdf). There is a statement in the proof of Theorem 2.4: “every submodule of $Rm$ is of the form $Im$ with a suitable left ideal $I$”, with $M$ is an $R$-module and $m\in M$, $Rm$ is the cyclic submodule of $M$. I know $Im$ is a submodule of $Rm$, but is every submodule of $Rm$ in the form $Im$? Which means that every submodule of cyclic module is cyclic? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

No: ${}_RR$ itself is a cyclic module, but of course it rarely has only cyclic submodules.

But consider the homomorphism $\phi: {}_RR \to {}_RRm$ given by $1\mapsto m$. By the first isomorphism theorem $R/L_m\cong Rm$. Each submodule in $Rm$ corresponds to a left ideal $I$ of $R$ containing $L_m$, whose image $\phi(I)=Im$.

You see, it simply does not follow that $Im$ has to be cyclic.  It *looks* cyclic because everything has the form $im$, but do you think you can select a single $im\in Im$ such that $Rim=Im$?

Comment: Of course $Rim\subseteq Im$, but if I take $x=am\in Im$ with $a\in I$, then $am$ not necessarily in $Rim$. So, $Im \neq Rim$ and $Im$ is not cyclic. Thank you for considering my question.